# Splitting a list and storing to CSV

Tags: list, split, storage

I'm having fun learning python but again need a bit of help. I've printed the output from the terminal to a txt.file, the output looks like this:

//Reaction PRISM_solar_litho at 0x109cfa5f8//, //Reaction PRISM_solar_exo at 0x11cebe7b8//

As you can see its a list of comma-separated reactions, there are ~2K reactions.

I want to write some code that will split the list into individual reactions at the ',' so I can then store each reaction into a different row of a CSV.  Can you help me please?

my code so far looks like this:

```
reactions_photo = []
myfile = open("iCZ843_photo_reactions.txt")
for line in myfile:
line.split(',')
myfile.close()
```

But how do I then store (append??) each reaction to the list of 'reactions_photo' and how do I print this to a CSV so that each reaction is on a new row?

Thank you kindly.

Stephen

Comment: Partly solved: I can now access the correct field and store this as a list:    with open('iCZ843_photo_reactions.txt','r+') as f:
 reactions = f.readlines() 
 for line in reactions:
  print (line)
#[<Reaction PRISM_solar_litho at 0x109cfa5f8>,.....<Reaction DDPGACv at 0x11d6e2438>]  
  f.close()
  reaction_auto = line.split(',')
  print(len(reaction_auto))


reaction_id_list = []
for line in reaction_auto:
    react, reaction_auto_id, at, mem = line.split()
    reaction_id_list.append(reaction_auto_id)
     print(reaction_id_list)
    print(len(reaction_id_list))

Comment: Completed using: with open('reactions_iCZ843.csv', 'w') as output:
 writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
 writer.writerow(['Reaction'])
 for val in reaction_id_list:
  writer.writerow([val])